# @media print @page margins not working on Mac Safari and iPad

Tags: css, reactjs, macos, ipad, safari

I am working on print a PDF from HTML page, and I have set the margin's on @page under the @media print. It's working fine on Windows browsers and Android tablets, but in Mac Safari and iPads are not working.

This rules I am using:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        margin-top: 20%;
        margin-bottom: 10%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 5%;
    }
}
```

I have tried value in "pt", "px" and "in" also.

What can I try next?